# How to open firefox plugin using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

Friends,

Is it possible to open any firefox plugin using javascript.

In general scenario is to open Selenium IDE plugin from our website on a button click and pre populate its fields like scripts paths/test data file pat etc and start execution of test cases.

We want to reduce the user intervention while executing the test cases.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by ff plugin? Can you give me an example so I can hopefully show you how its done.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I mean like "Selenium IDE" is a Selenium plugin for FF to execute test cases. I want some javascript way to open this plugin automatically without letting user to click on it and hopefully fill out fields too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites cannot script extensions in general. This would be highly insecure as websites run with limited privileges while extensions do not.

So unless the Selenium IDE extension provides specific ways to let a website interact with it (not the other ways round; consult their docs, but IIRC they don't), you're out of luck.